# Does Swift have access to main

Tags: swift

If you run the following code in the Swift REPL, it will print out `main.SomeClass`. Here is a Swiftstub to try it out: http://swiftstub.com/887338044

```
class SomeClass {
    func doesSomething() {
        print(self) // prints "main.SomeClass
    }
}

let someClass = SomeClass()
someClass.doesSomething()
```

Is it possible to get access to `main` the object/variable/constant to inspect it? What is main?

Comment: To whoever down-voted, do you want to explain why?

Answer (score 3):

You are always in a module (namespace). In an iOS app, it's the app, and it has the name of the project by default (you can change that in the build settings). In the REPL, we have to make something up, so the module is called `main`. It isn't an "object", "variable", or "constant" that you can "access"; it's just the namespace. Your class's real name simply *is* `main.SomeClass`.

Comment: So variables/constants that you type directly into the playground don't exist in a base class of any kind? If not where do they exist? I'm thinking in relation to Javascript where variables wind up in the `window` object.

Comment: They exist at top level of the special `main` function. That is why you are allowed to do things in the REPL that you cannot do except at top level of a Swift file in real life.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? And I guess we don't have access to that `main` function?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "access". You are _in_ it. It is the entry point within which everything is happening. You have access to it exactly in the sense that you have access to everything you have already said: you define a class in one line, then you instantiate that class in another line, because it is all happening in one "place".

Comment: What I want to do in the end is get a list of global variables that are declared in `main`. I figured main would be a class or something I could inspect. So when I say access, that is what I meant. In this dumb example: http://swiftstub.com/43001410/ I can reference a function. I figured if I had reference to said base class (or function) I could then figure out a way to list the global variables/constants within it.

Comment: In French, "figure" means "imagine". Everything you've just said is pure imagination.